# Creating a log having the date of purchase

Tags: mysql, date

I need to create a log having the purchase date of an item.

Items can be owned by only one buyer at time. So, for example, if `item1` was purchased by `buyer2` in 2009 and after by `buyer1` in 2015, then between 2009 and 2015 was owned by `buyer2`.

Here is my table:

```
+--------+------------+-----------+----------+
| id_doc | date       | id_item   | id_buyer |
+--------+------------+-----------+----------+
|     11 | 2016-06-07 | 1         |        4 |
|     10 | 2016-06-06 | 1         |        4 |
|      1 | 2015-11-30 | 1         |        1 |
|      9 | 2009-01-01 | 1         |        2 |
|      4 | 2001-01-12 | 1         |        2 |
|      8 | 1996-06-06 | 1         |        2 |
|      3 | 1995-05-29 | 1         |        1 |
|      2 | 1998-05-23 | 2         |        2 |
|      7 | 2014-10-10 | 3         |        2 |
|      6 | 2003-12-12 | 3         |        3 |
|      5 | 1991-01-12 | 3         |        2 |
+--------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

Here is a kind of table/view I need:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+----------+--------+
| date_from  | date_to    | id_item   | id_buyer | id_doc |
+------------+------------+-----------+----------+--------+
| 2016-06-07 | -          | 1         |        4 |     11 |
| 2016-06-06 | 2016-06-07 | 1         |        4 |     10 |
| 2015-11-30 | 2016-06-06 | 1         |        1 |      1 |
| 2009-01-01 | 2015-11-30 | 1         |        2 |      9 |
| 2001-01-12 | 2009-01-01 | 1         |        2 |      4 |
| 1996-06-06 | 2001-01-12 | 1         |        2 |      8 |
| 1995-05-29 | 1996-06-06 | 1         |        1 |      3 |
| 1998-05-23 | -          | 2         |        2 |      2 |
| 2014-10-10 | -          | 3         |        2 |      7 |
| 2003-12-12 | 2014-10-10 | 3         |        3 |      6 |
| 1991-01-12 | 2003-12-12 | 3         |        2 |      5 |
+------------+------------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

I've tried a lot with `GROUP BY`, `GROUP_CONCAT`, trying to access next record date, etc ... but I can't found out how to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the solution only for past purchases.

```
SELECT 
    main.id_doc, main.id_item, main.date AS "date_from", bi.date AS "date_to", main.id_buyer
FROM 
    MyTable main, MyTable bi
WHERE 
    bi.id_doc = 
    (
        SELECT sub.id_doc 
        FROM MyTable sub 
        WHERE sub.id_item = main.id_item AND sub.date > main.date ORDER BY sub.date ASC LIMIT 1
    );
```